# web server always change mode to "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY"

Tags: mysql, cakephp

As I reinstall old project for my customer and the service is working fine but I found sometimes it can't query some information. from checking it's because @@Global.sql_mode and @@SESSION.sql_mode set to "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" 
the step to solve it need to run command

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`
nowadays it's happen 3 times per week.

So any way can I fix it permanent?

Comment: Speak to your service provider?

Comment: It's probably best to fix the query, if you're able that is.

Comment: Do you have control over the MySQL instance or is this a shared hosting environment? You could add your `SET GLOBAL...` query in the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the server instance then edit the config file to turn off ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

The above will probably return something similar to this -

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Then you can add the following to your config file (same list as above with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY removed) -

```
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Depending on your CakePHP version, you could add a settings key to your db config -

```
        'settings' => array(
            '@@SESSION.sql_mode' => "'TRADITIONAL'",
        ),
```